# How do I create instances of qstackedwidget pages correctly?

Tags: pyqt

QMainWindow contain a QStackedWidget and buttons for switching QStackedWidget pages? The code for each QStackedWidget page is written in separate StackedWidget_page_0 classes. For example, there is a button1 on the page that opens the QDialog. if you navigate through the QStackedWidget pages several times, the button1 starts opening several instances of QDialog.The problem was solved by comparing the id. In the switch_pages method, it does not delete instances when the page is switched, so several QDialogs are opened for each instance. How to redo the switch_pages method so that one instance is created and deleted when switching.

```
class QStackedWidget_page_0(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(QStackedWidget_page_0, self).__init__()
        self.data = data

class QStackedWidget_page_1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(QStackedWidget_page_0, self).__init__()
        self.data = data

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('qt_designer_ui/test.ui', self)

        self.cur_page = None
        self.switch_widget(0)

        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.switch_pages(0))
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.switch_pages(1))

    def switch_pages(self, index):
        widget = {0: QStackedWidget_page_0,
                  1: QStackedWidget_page_1,
                  }
        self.cur_page = widget[index](self)
        self.MyQStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Before asking how to remove an existing instance, it would be important to understand why you need to create new instances of the same classes every time. QStackedWidget is a paged container, similar to QTabWidget: each tab (page) is intended to be used again by switching to it, instead of being added again. If the problem is clearing the contents of some fields, then you should create a function that does that, so that you don't need to destroy and recreate the same widget all over again. If no pages are intended to be reused, then maybe QStackedWidget is not what you need.